# Filename Variables in Win CE .bat files

Tags: batch-file, embedded, windows-ce

Im trying to use a .bat file on an embedded industrial HMI to copy some files. I want to time/date stamp a folder name, and then copy some stuff into it. I have got the meat of it working, it copies the file when commanded. But i cant seem to get variables to behave as they do on my laptop. Instead of inserting the variable, it literally puts % in the filename. What am i missing?

Code

```
SET "datestamp=220404"
mkdir "\Data Backup\%datestamp%"
COPY "\Log Data\*.*" "\Data Backup\%datestamp%"
exit
```

Makes a folder named "%datestamp%"

I have tried using echo to visualise the problem, and it again just gives me %datestamp%

Any ideas?

Comment: Windows CE does not support environment variables. You'll have to use the registry or add manual entries.

Comment: can you do me a favor though? from `cmd` run only the command `set` and let me know the output. Maybe a screenshot

Comment: so there's your proof then. if `set` returns nothing it just does not have environment variables. `:)` The reason why `set` was added to CE is a mystery as it serves no purpose. it purely set's environment variables.

Comment: yes, but the variables will never exist because it does not support them. so `set "var=value"` will not give a result if you do `echo %var%`

Comment: @AnonCoward, yes, that is a longer way to state what I have said in my first comment.